# How to resolve metadata exception when install the package in visual studio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, nuget

I am trying to install a package using NuGet package manager in VS 2019, but i am facing below issue when restoring or installing the package:

> "Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'NETStandard.Library.1.6.1' from source 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder'"

How to resolve this issue?

Please let me know, if you know about this issue.

Comment: Which version of VS 2019? What package? What kind of project template? What framework version for the project?

Comment: @RezaAghaei i have installed 16.4 latest version. i could not update xamarin forms packages too. .net framework version 2.1

Comment: Which nuget package version did you install? Did your xamarin forms project target to `.Net Standard 1.6`? Also, please make sure that you installed the `.Net Core 2.2` in your VS which supports `.Net Standard 1.6`.

Comment: Issue has been resolved, due to not installing .net core framework as 2.1. i have installed framework version 3.0. after installed .net core framework as 2.1. its working fine.